# Don't show Image in Webbrowser in .Net compact Framework

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, .net-cf-3.5

I want to show only text in the Webbrowser, don't allow show Image.
But i don't have idea.
could you help me some idea, please.!
Thank very much.!